# Installing maven 3.0.4

Tags: java, linux, maven

I have been trying to install maven 3.0.4 using Ubuntu command line from windows 10 with following command:

```
sudo apt-get install maven
```

this command install maven 3.0.4

```
sudo apt-get install maven2
```

this command install maven 2.2.1

Is there any specific command for particularly installing maven 3.0.4? 
Actually I have to run a project which is maven build and Linux executable scripts. I'm a windows user and I don't know a lot about Linux stuff.

Comment: noo im running it on ubuntu command line and its working okkk

Comment: i need to install specific version of maven 3.0.4 im asking if there is any way to install it becoz  sudo apt-get install maven gives me maven 3.0.5 and sudo apt-get install gives me version 2.2.1

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/428772/how-to-install-specific-version-of-some-package